# Google Vision Api text recognition for iOS

Tags: ocr, google-vision, google-ios-vision

I played with text recognition for android code samples in https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision. But i could not find any samples for iOS. https://github.com/googlesamples/ios-vision.

Is the iOS text recognizer available yet ?